# replacing icon after text changed of editbox in android

Tags: android

I have editbox in my application. beside to editbox i have one search icon. whenever user entered any single character i want to replace search icon with one more icon(cross icon) and if user removed all his/her text from editbox again i want search icon.

For this I used below code.

mSearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
 @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence searchString, int start, int before, int count) {
            initCloseSearchView();              
            if (mDealerAdapter != null) {
                    mDealerAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchString);
                }              

            }
    @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }
    @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             log.d(TAG, "inside afterTextChanged");
        }
});

private void initCloseSearchView(){     
  int textLength = mSearchView.length();
  log.d(TAG, "textLength  "+textLength);
  if(textLength >= 1){
    searchIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    View searchView = (View) mLayoutSearch.findViewById(R.id.search);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)searchView.getParent();
    int indexOfSearchView = parent.indexOfChild(searchView);
    log.d(TAG, "index of search==>"+indexOfSearchView);
    ImageButton closeSearch = new                       ImageButton(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    closeSearch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close_search);
    mLayoutSearch.addView(closeSearch, indexOfSearchView);
  }else{
            searchIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

  }
```

with above code I am able to replace search icon with cross icon but when user delete his/her text from edit box cross icon is appearing more than one time. How to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: could you add screenshot of your layout and xml, if you use. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mSearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

 @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence searchString, int start, int before, int count) {
            initCloseSearchView();     
             if(count == 0){
              // set first image 
             }else{
               // set second image 
             }

            if (mDealerAdapter != null) {
                    mDealerAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchString);
                }              

            }
    @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }
    @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             log.d(TAG, "inside afterTextChanged");
        }
});
```

set image according to your requirement

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xxx);
    initCloseSearchView();
}

mSearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence searchString, int start, int before, int count) {               
         if (mDealerAdapter != null) { 
             mDealerAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchString);
         }               
    } 
    @Override 
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

    } 
    @Override 
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         log.d(TAG, "inside afterTextChanged");
         boolean isShowSearch = s.getText().toString().length() > 0 ?false:true;
         updateCloseSearchView(isShowSearch); 
    } 
}); 

private void initCloseSearchView(){      
/*    int textLength = mSearchView.length();
    log.d(TAG, "textLength  "+textLength);
    if(textLength >= 1){
        searchIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        View searchView = (View) mLayoutSearch.findViewById(R.id.search);
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)searchView.getParent();
        int indexOfSearchView = parent.indexOfChild(searchView);
        log.d(TAG, "index of search==>"+indexOfSearchView);
        ImageButton closeSearch = new                               ImageButton(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        closeSearch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close_search);
        mLayoutSearch.addView(closeSearch, indexOfSearchView);
    }else{ 
        searchIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } */
    //init the view
    //TODO
    closeSearch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close_search);
    closeSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    searchIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void updateIcon(boolean isShowSearch){
    if(isShowSearch){
        closeSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        searchIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        closeSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        searchIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

by the way . the Member variable should start with prefix m.   searchIcon -> mSearchIcon. closeSearch -> mCloseSearch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried previous answer it is working for me. But your answer is also close solution to my problem. Keep it up. good

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not take care when the text length is 0, 
You have added a view every time the user entered some text. you need to remove that view when the user deletes the text in the editText.

create a flag and set it to 1 when you add the closeSearch View and check that flag if it equals to 1 in the else part. if it is equal to 1 then remove you closeSearch View.